# Swift iOS -Tab Bar Disappears After BackButton is pressed but new ViewController appears Modally

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue

Inside storyBoards I have a `tabBar` connected to a `navController` and it has 3 child viewControllers connected to it: `firstVC`, `secondVC`, `thirdVC`.

```
                                              BackButton
                                             /     |
                                            /      |
tabBarController -> navController -> firstVC -> secondVC -> thirdVC
                                        |       /  |       /
                                        |      /   |      / //completion{performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToThirdVC", sender: nil)}
                                     buttonOne   buttonTwo
```

Inside `firstVC` I have `buttonOne` that pushes (show) on `secondVC`

Inside `secondVC` I have `buttonTwo` that pushes (show) on `thirdVC` using performSegueWithIdentifier. The reason being is I make a network call and wait to get some data back and then inside the completion handler I call performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToThirdVC", sender: nil). Inside IB I have the `segue` connected from `secondVC` to `thirdVC` using the `viewController icon` instead of using `buttonTwo`.

SecondVC

```
@IBAction func buttonTwo(sender: UIButton){

   someNetworkCall... completion{
     //the segue does't happen until the data comes back
     performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToThirdVC", sender: nil)//I also tried self

    //I also tried it programmatically but nope:
    //storyBoard: UIStoryBoard = UIStoryBoard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    //let thirdVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ThirdController") as! ThirdController
    //navigationController?.pushViewController(thirdVC, animated: true)
     }
}
```

The `secondVC` also has a `BackButton` that I automatically get from the `navController`. The `BackButton` obviously leads to `firstVC`.

I get the data back and the segue works ***but the problem is if I fiddle around and press the `BackButton` inside the `secondVC` at the right moment***, I can literally see 3 things happen at once:

1. the `secondVC` slides to the right to expose the `firstVC` (the BackButton is working)
2. the `thirdVC` pops up **modally** exposing itself???
3. the `tabBarController` completely **disappears** because the `thirdVC` **obscures** it (I can see it cover it)

The final outcome is the `thirdVC` presented modally with no `BackButton`leading to the `secondVC` and no `tabBarController`. It's as if a completely new `thirdVC` was instantiated separate from the `tabBarController` and no connection to `secondVC` nor the `navContoller`.

**Why is my tabBarController being obscured and the thirdVC disconnecting from the hierarchy?**

Btw I'm able to see all 3 things happening at once because inside the simulator I use `Slow Animations`. If I don't fiddle around and press the `BackButton` inside the `secondVC` everything works fine: I get the `thirdVC` pushed on like it's supposed to, it has it's own `BackButton` leading to the `secondVC`, and the `tabBarController's tabs` are visible at the bottom.

Comment: did u got the answer for the same ?

Comment: @Satish  nope never found the answer for this. I got around it by disabling the back button when buttonTwo is pressed and enabling it once the completion is finished.

Comment: Okay.. let me dig more